# Store/Index time in mongo, use a timestamp or a date/time

Tags: mongodb, datetime, indexing, unix-timestamp

When storing a timestamp in mongodb should I store the 'unix-time' millis since some date or should I store an actual date/time?

What are the benefits of either?

Edit

To be more specific should I store a long that is seconds since Jan 1. 1970, or should I store a Javascript date object.

Comment: Can you be more specific with examples. What do you mean actual time?

Comment: JS Date or epoch seconds since Jan 1. 1970.  There is more than one way to represent a time in mongo, how should I represent it and why is one better than another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the MongoDB native date format.  The advantage of that is that you can then easily use the date operators:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/